# Copying data from one pandas dataframe to other based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe df1 and df2
df1 is like below

```
Index YH   HE  MT  CU  EI
 0    Dot  Sf  Sy  Lc  
 1    Rls  Bd  Sa  Ta  
 2    Fs       Ft  Rg
```

df2 is like

```
Index   Z1   Z2  Z3
 0      YH       HE
 1      HE       EI
 2      MT       CU
```

I want to copy values from df1 to df2 depending upon the cell value in df2 which matches with column name in df1
So my df3 should look like

df3

```
Index Z1   Z2   Z3
  0   YH        HE
  1   Dot       Sf  
  2   Rls       Bd
  3   Fs        EI
  4   HE        CU
  5   Sf        Lc
  6   Bd        Ta
  7   MT        Rg
  8   Sy
  9   Sa
  10  Ft
```

Basically I want to copy the column from df1 in df2 depending upon cell value of df2 which is a column name in df1

If its still confusing please tell me

Comment: standard task in pandas, see docs on `loc` for the standard approach but numpy `where` also works well.  again, just see the docs or any of the hundreds of stack overflow questions that address this  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involve a lot of function ...

```
s=df2.set_index('Index').astype(object).apply(lambda x : x.map(df1.set_index('Index').to_dict('l')))
m=pd.concat([df2.set_index('Index').applymap(lambda x : [x]),s]).sort_index().sum(level=0).sum()
pd.DataFrame(m.tolist(),index=m.index).T.reindex(columns=df2.columns[1:]).fillna('')
Out[1721]: 
     Z1 Z2  Z3
0    YH     HE
1   Dot     Sf
2   Rls     Bd
3    Fs       
4    HE     EI
5    Sf       
6    Bd       
7             
8    MT     CU
9    Sy     Lc
10   Sa     Ta
11   Ft     Rg
```

To get what you need

```
pd.DataFrame(m.tolist(),index=m.index).T.reindex(columns=df2.columns[1:]).replace('',np.nan).dropna(thresh=1,axis=0).fillna('')
Out[1724]: 
     Z1 Z2  Z3
0    YH     HE
1   Dot     Sf
2   Rls     Bd
3    Fs       
4    HE     EI
5    Sf       
6    Bd       
8    MT     CU
9    Sy     Lc
10   Sa     Ta
11   Ft     Rg
```

Comment: Index is not a seperate column.It is just the default index of dataframe

Comment: @Rookie_123 yep, so you do not need set_index() : -)

Comment: Yeah :) I was just telling so that other's wont get confused :)

Comment: The solution is awesome Got a new approach for it Thanks for it :)

Comment: @Rookie_123 yw~ :-) happy coding

Comment: Can you please look over the edit and suggest for it